# How can I stop my kitten from growing?

Tags: cats

I acquired my cat 1 month ago.  She is now 8 months old and substantially larger than when I rescued her from the shelter.  How can I stop her from growing larger?

Thanks.

Comment: This would be cute _and_ funny if it weren't for the concern that some people actually do junk like this, [even to human beings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot_binding), and might then be encouraged to do this to their helpless pets.  As crazy as it is, there're actually those sorts out there...

Comment: Related discussion [HNQ](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2281/13)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Erm.. you can't. At least not without severely harming the health of the kitten.

Small living things grow into bigger living things - this is a nearly universal phenomenon.

Depending on the breed of the cat however it may be that it has *nearly* reached it's full growth - the majority of breeds have their growth slow significantly around the 12 month mark and grow significantly slower until around 18 months old where they are fully grown.

Some larger breeds such as Maine Coons, Norwegian Forest Cats and Birmans can take 2-4 years before they are fully grown.

Comment: I want her to stay smol tho.  She's my little lady. :c

Comment: @hownowbrowncow I'm sorry, but I have to ask... What kinda question is that? Honestly, if that is all you care about, then maybe you're not suited to keep a pet.

Comment: @hownowbrowncow on the off chance that you aren't just trolling may I suggest that you find the kitten/cat a suitable home with someone who understands that pets aren't toys and can be responsible enough to care for her properly and get yourself a plush toy cat instead. Guaranteed not grow a whisker larger.

Answer (score 22):

You're not going to stop an animal from growing larger without seriously endangering their well-being. She is *supposed* to be whatever size she is growing to. The only reasons that they wouldn't would be serious malnourishment or hormonal problems. Intentionally causing either would be clear animal abuse and would severely shorten her life.

Let her be healthy and grow! She'll still be the same cat you know and love.

Answer (score 16):

There is in fact a way to keep your cat how it is: Photographs.

They're a wonderful invention, and you can even keep cameras in your pocket now.

Photos are:

- Guaranteed not to grow
- Easy to copy. Cats run away; flash drives do too, but you can back them up
- Still cute
- Instagram postable
- Convenient to store and share. Animals do not fit on Micro SD cards.

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried reasoning with it? Okay, seriously, the term "substantially larger" is kind of vague. So I'll consider two possibilities:

1. The kitten has become a cat. Not much you can do about this.
2. The cat is overweight. If this is the case, then you are probably feeding it too much. A lot of people just fill a bowl and let the cat eat it whenever, but for a fat cat, you'll have to restrict its diet. Follow the recommendations on the food you give it, and don't leave the food out all day.

Posting a photo of the cat would be helpful. If you are like most people, you probably have hundreds of photos by now....

Answer (score 7):

As noted, you don't stop a kitten's growth without endangering its health/life.

If you want a cat of a certain size, next time you're adopting a cat go to a shelter and adopt an adult of that size.

Answer (score 4):

You are putting your self-interest ahead of the well-betting of the poor animal. Please don't do anything to stunt its natural growth.

If you cannot accept the nature of an animal tip grow to a normal size,

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to harm your cat in such a way? There is a reason why they *naturally* grow, and attempting to stunt your cat's growth could cause **major** health issues. This is one of the worst questions I have ever seen.

Answer (score -2):

I don't quite know how to accomplish this either...and to anyone who says it's cruel or anything like that there is never harm in a question. Intact I was wondering the same thing not because I don't want a full grown cat or anything like that it's just when they are little and playful and so dang cute you don't want them to grow into a fully grown cat.  Because well if you had  a tiny one like that. You don't want the little puff ball to grow up. Not because I want to hurt it. It's just that it won't be a cute as hetck kitten.

Comment: If you want a cat that stays small(ish) and playful as an adult, you can look for breeds that *naturally* have those characteristics.